# best way to use a second CSS file to define the printing settings of a single page

Tags: html, css

I have multiple pages that are styled by a single CSS file, and all the pages follow the same print rules in the CSS.

Now I have a new page that I want to be printed only in landscape mode, now that I have the css code for it:

```
@page {
size: A4 landscape;
size: 287mm 210mm;
```

as I can't define a class for the @page attribute, so if I put this in the single CSS file I have currently it will apply on every htm document, I figured I need a secondary CSS file to cover the print settings for that single page.

My question is, what is the best way to add this second CSS file?
As much as I know, if I just declare the @page attribute like in the example above, when the pages get compiled, the CSS files will be merged right? So I'll have again different @page attributes.

Is my only solution to copy in the second CSS file everything that is styling the page, not only the print options, and just

```
<link type="stylesheet" href="printDoc.css" rel="printStylesheet" />
```

put this line in the interested htm page? 
I hoped (because the CSS code is really long) that I could only define print options in the second CSS file, and make the interested htm page take the styling settings for the body from the main CSS file, and the styling for the printing for the secondary CSS file, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just with using an in page [style element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) for that one page you want printed.

```
 <style type="text/css" media="print">
   @page {
     size: A4 landscape;
     size: 287mm 210mm;
  </style>
```

Or if you want both just add them to the page, anything in b.css will overwrite the style in a.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a.css">
<link media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="b.css">
```

Comment: didn't think about this, so this will take priority over the @page attribute of the main css file?

And IF I wanted to have a separate css file anyway, what would be the best solution?

Comment: Yeah the cascading effect works with element style > page style > external file style. IF you wanted to have the second style sheet just make sure it is loaded after the first one. You can have as many style sheets as you want, if that main style sheet is really long you could also look into something like http://lesscss.org/ or http://sass-lang.com/ to help you break it down into smaller chunks while you are developing.

Comment: But even if the second stylesheet is loaded after the first one,
my doub is in the @page attribute! 

How it will be handled? Because both style sheets would have a (at)page attribute, and as I can't define classes on that attribute, how would that work? How can the compiler know it needs to apply the (at)page attribute in the main CSS file to every page, but for that specific page I want in landscape, it needs to apply the (at)page style of the second style sheet?

Comment: You would need to attach the second css file only to the page(s) you want to be printed in landscape mode. I am not sure how you are generating the pages so have no idea if you using templates or a cms? But as you only want it on one page, adding it as a page style tag has small benefits like one less network request.

Comment: ok so just to be clear I understood correctly, the first css file is applied to every page (it s an angularJS webapp), and if I were to create a second css file with only the @page attribute to print in landscape, I would need to attach it ONLY to the interested htm page, and in this case, the compiler would apply all the rules of the first css file to that page, and when it finds the same attribute in both css files (in this case (at)page ), it would take in consideration only the one of the second css file?

Comment: Yeah exactly, the second(newest) @ page attributes would override the @ page attributes in the first css file.